# outOfMemoryError from javacv

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv

We are using `javacv` library for creating thumbnails out of videos. We are able to create thumbnails. But when we upload more videos `(20 to 30 of 10MB to 40MB)` the application is throwing outOfMemoryError.

We are using `1.3.1` version of `javacv`.
Here is the `pom.xml` file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the code

```
public BufferedImage generateThumbnail(File outputVideoFile) throws IOException {
      BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    try {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(outputVideoFile);
        frameGrabber.start();
        Frame grabKeyFrame = frameGrabber.grabKeyFrame();
        Java2DFrameConverter java2DFrameConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
        bufferedImage = java2DFrameConverter.convert(grabKeyFrame);
        frameGrabber.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return bufferedImage;
}
```

Here is the error

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes = 3G > maxPhysicalBytes = 3G
org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:562)
org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:121)
org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.allocate(Native Method)
org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<init>(avcodec.java:1696)
org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:471)
org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:462)
org.bahmni.module.bahmnimsf.extension.PatientDocumentThumbnailGenerator.generateThumbnail(PatientDocumentThumbnailGenerator.java:40)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
```

I tried to upgrade the version to `1.4` though it's not working.
Somebody told me to use `System.gc()` that also not working.

Can someone suggest the solution? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried extracting key frames using ffmpeg in the console?
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I),scale=100x100" \
-vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 thumbnails-%02d.jpg`
(Just to make sure it's not ffmpeg having trouble processing your input file)

Comment: You might also be interested in https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/875

Comment: I posted this same question in javacv community. They accepted it as issue.
here are the details https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/911

Comment: @MaharjunM Have you got solution of this issue? Because i have still find out solution of this issue.

Comment: I did not find the solution. I had a workaround for it. I reported in the FFmpegFrameGrabber repo. It seems they are working on it. Issue link https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/911#issuecomment-365344391

Comment: You can increase the heapsize so that RAM size for the application will increase meanwhile Java garbage collector will frees some memory. You can use `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms4g -Xmx7g` for setting up minimum and max size of heapSize